Logic Apps Data Mapper Loop
I am currently working in the new Logic Apps Data Mapper and I simply wanted to ask if there is anything similar to the old Looping Functoid we have seen in the BizTalk mapper.
I currently have a source schema (json) which has one array. My destination schema has an array that holds another array. The nested array holds the values I need to map to, however I am currently unable to do do due to a missing "looping" functoid.
Thanks in advance!
I have tried directly mapping the 2 arrays to the destination array however this simply creates double values.

as per official document, When you first create a mapping relationship between a matching pair of array items, a mapping relationship is automatically created at the parent array level.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-maps-data-transformation-visual-studio-code#create-a-loop-between-arrays

